# Bug in Breeze 1.01 with boolean field and canceling changes

Tags: breeze

I have an issue in BreezeJs 1.01 when canceling changes on a Boolean property. The property is bound using KnockoutJs:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="IsDeleted" data-bind="checked: IsDeleted" />
```

It has the following behavior:

1. If the initial value is true, and I set it to false, then cancel changes, the value reverts to true. (correct behavior)
2. If the initial value is false, and I set it to true, then cancel changes, the value reverts to false. (correct behavior)
3. If the initial value is true, and I set it to false and then back to true, then cancel changes, the value stays true. (correct behavior)
4. If the initial value is false, and I set it to true and then back to false, then cancel changes, the value reverts to true. (incorrect behavior)

Comment: Do you get this same behavior without using the binding. i.e. when just calling the setters and getters directly?

Comment: Yes, I just confirmed I get the same behavior calling the getters, setters and cancelChanges directly.

Comment: Great, and thanks. I should be able to look into this later today and get a fix out "soon".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry this took so long.  This was a bug and is now fixed in breeze v 1.1.0.  and thanks for finding it :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. Breeze is awesome.